# Keen IO Junks data with KeenIOClient for Android

Tags: android, keen-io

Trying to use IO Keen for Android, i'm using Android Sample available here (https://github.com/keenlabs/KeenClient-Android-Sample) the data is being sent, but they are always duplicate and the second always contains junk.

The HashMap event is clean before adding in the queue.

Am I the only one?

Watch these  :

```
{
    "keen": {
        "timestamp": "2015-01-22T18:08:49.863Z",
        "created_at": "2015-01-22T18:09:07.589Z",
        "id": "54c13cc3672e6c486c7a28bb"
    },
    "click-number": 0
}   

{
    "keen": {
        "timestamp": "2015-01-22T18:09:07.590Z",
        "created_at": "2015-01-22T18:09:07.590Z",
        "id": "54c13cc3672e6c486c7a28bc"
    },
    "-537732783": 3
}
```

`"-537732783": 3`   What is that?

Logcat :

```
FINER: Sent request '{"android-sample-button-clicks":[{"click-number":0,"keen":{"timestamp":"2015-01-22T13:14:19.075-0500"}}]}' to URL 'https://api.keen.io [...]

FINER: Received response: '{"android-sample-button-clicks": [{"success": true}]}' (200)

FINER: Sent request '{"android-sample-button-clicks":[{"-1236199318":1}]}' to URL 'https://api.keen.io [...]

FINER: Received response: '{"android-sample-button-clicks": [{"success": true}]}' (200)
```

Comment: We've confirmed that this is a bug, and will get out a 2.1.1 patch ASAP. In the meantime if you're blocked we'd recommend rolling back to the 2.0.3 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in the 2.1.0 release of the SDK. It has been fixed in the 2.1.1 release.

(In more detail: the bug was in the retry limiting logic that was added as part of 2.1. See this PR for the fix: https://github.com/keenlabs/KeenClient-Java/pull/37)

Sorry for the mistake!